# systemd run service during the day

Tags: internet, systemd, timer

I would like to set up my server so that it only connects to the internet during the day.

I created a timer file:
    [Unit]
    Description=Start and stop the internet

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar*-*-* 06:00:00
Unit=netctl@wlan0_sta/x2dInternet.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But how do I make this shutdown the internet service at the end of the day?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second "service" that also runs on a timer at the end of the day.. Set the "ExecStart=" line of the second service to simply run the shutdown command of the first service:

```
 ExecStart=/bin/systemctl stop my-service-name.service
```